# Why does the MessagePack error extension (0x03) have top-level MP_MAP?

Tags: msgpack, tarantool

In Tarantool 2.4.1, a new MessagePack [extension](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.4/reference/reference_lua/box_error/) was introduced to serialize errors. At the very top level of the extension body there is a map with only one element, an error stack (an array consisting of error maps). I wonder if this top-level map can contain more than one element, and if not, why it is needed at all? Why not just have an error stack as the extension body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer.

Currently (in 2.4.1) it contains only one field, IPROTO_ERROR_STACK (0). But in future more fields may be added to this map. The format of MP_MAP with a single key is chosen for better extendibility. All connectors should be able to parse IPROTO_ERROR_STACK key, and skip any other key. So even if in future Tarantool versions new fields are added to the map, the old connectors still would be able to parse responses.

#### Long answer.

In Tarantool most of the responses of the binary protocol (IProto) have form of a MessagePack map: MP_MAP. Even if there is just 1 or 2 fields in this map, it is still MP_MAP, not an MP_ARRAY, and of course not just a non-formatted byte array.

Some such responses exist for many years. There appear lots of connectors to Tarantool, which are able to send/receive and parse responses from Tarantool in IProto protocol.

And when it becomes necessary to change something in these responses after all the years of exploitation with all the created software to handle the responses, the MP_MAP comes in hand. With MP_MAP it is easy to add new fields into the response not breaking all the old connectors. Assuming that they are ready that some new unknown keys may be received, and they just skip them.

This is why MP_MAP is used in Tarantool a lot as a top level of response type. It is easy to extend and not break old code. Error MessagePack format, with IPROTO_ERROR_STACK, is MP_MAP by the same reason. In future there may be added more keys to the error object.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!